# Can I bring a wooden dough rolling stick onto the plane(carry-on)?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage, tsa, prohibited-items

Here is a picture of what I am trying to bring onto the plane. I thought since it is wooden, it might pose a threat. I'd really appreciate any help.

Flying from LGA, NYC, and I do not have any checked in baggage because it is Basic Economy flight.

[image]

Comment: The security rules and limits you'll face depend on several factors: the location of the departing airport, the flight's destination, and the identity of the carrier. As asked, it's impossible to answer. OTOH, given that this object is large enough to be wielded as a weapon, I think it's unlikely to be accepted as a carry-on. Put it in checked baggage, or leave it home.

Comment: @David: The [tag:tsa] tag suggests that the poster is flying in the US, or at least departing from there.  In the US, security rules are mainly set by the TSA and are pretty uniform across airlines.  So I think this should be answerable.

Comment: Even with Basic Economy you can still check bags - you just have to pay, same as for regular economy tickets.  So you get to decide whether it's worth $25 or whatever to bring this with you, or if it's better to leave it behind, ship it to your destination, etc.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right, I glossed right over that info. OTOH, others who view this page might find it useful to be reminded that the rules under circumstances X may be difference from those under circumstances Y.

Comment: FWIW, some destinations may also have regulations regarding importing wooden items.  If you're flying from LGA to Australia, for example, you'll probably at least have to declare the item and be prepared to submit it for inspection upon arriving.

Comment: They allow [musical instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapstick#/media/File:Didgeridu_and_clap_sticks.jpg).

Comment: Practically each man in every joke coming home late with his wife disapproving will agree that that is a weapon.

Comment: Looks like it would fit inside a poster tube and postage would be the cheapest solution, cheaper than checking a bag.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I asked https://www.facebook.com/AskTSA and they've told me that it is not allowed in carry-on bags.

> (12:44:55 PM) **Ask TSA**: We're glad you asked! Rolling pins must be
>   packed in checked bags. Safe travels! -Kirsey
>
> (12:46:42 PM) **可买**: So I cannot bring them onto the plane with my
>   carry-on luggage? (I don't have any checked in luggage)
>
> (12:53:15 PM) **Ask TSA**: That's correct.. Rolling pins aren't allowrd in
>   carry-on bags. - Kirsey
>
> (12:53:24 PM) **可买**: Thank you Kirsey!

[image]

Comment: If you've answered your own question and there is no better answer, you should accept your answer.

Comment: I wanted to add an update, I successfully got through TSA in EWR with the rolling pin. However, I still don't suggest trying it, I think I was lucky and I only did it because this (second) time, I actually had a chance to check in my bag and if TSA refused, I was going to go back and check in.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind risking losing it I would take it with you anyway. The worst they are likely to do is confiscate it. If they decide that is what they want to do **accept it** to avoid further escalation.

I once flew with a piece of 1-inch diameter steel bar stock a foot long out of Stansted, London, UK, as I was going to see a friend in Spain who had a lathe and I didn't want the hassle of obtaining the item at my destination.

I was upfront about it: I placed my bag in the tray for the scanner, with the bar unpacked beside it. The tray was inevitably selected for further inspection. The security guy politely asked me why I was carrying the item. Convinced by my story and my non-threatening demeanor he called his supervisor. After the further pleasant conversation, they allowed me to keep the item, for which I thanked them.

I'm sure if I asked an official advice line if that kind of item were allowed they would tell me no. But I got lucky on the day. For a low-value item, it can be worth taking the risk.